# Error from Remix: "ParserError: Expected primary expression"

Tags: solidity, remix, ethereum-wallet-dapp

This is my code:

```
pragma solidity>0.4.99<0.6.0;

contract Election {

struct Candidate {
    string name;
    uint voteCount;
}

struct Voter {
    bool authorized;
    bool voted;
    uint vote;
}

address public owner;
string public electionName;

mapping(address => Voter) public voters;
Candidate[] public candidates;
uint public totalVotes;

modifier ownerOnly(){
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _;
}

function Election(string _name) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    electionName = _name;
}

function addCanditate(string _name) ownerOnly public {
    candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0));
}

function getNameCandidate() public view returns(uint){
    returns Candidate.length;
}

function authorize (address _person) ownerOnly public {
    voters[_person].authorized = true;
}

function vote (uint _voteIndex) public {
    require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
    require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);

    voters[msg.sender].vote = _voteIndex;
    voters[msg.sender].voted = true;

    Candidates[_voteIndex].voteCount += 1;
    totalVotes += 1;
}
function end() ownerOnly public {
    selfdestruct(owner);
}

}
```

I am facing a problem here:

```
function getNameCandidate() public view returns(uint){
    returns Candidate.length;
}
```

it's showing me this error:

> ```
> browser/Test.sol:38:5: ParserError: Expected primary expression.
>     returns Candidate.length;
>     ^-----^
> ```

How do I solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you return a value, you use the singular `return` not `returns`.

Comment: I changed returns to return and now I got two errors: function Election(string _name) public { owner = msg.sender; electionName = _name; } function addCanditate(string _name) ownerOnly public { candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0)); } in tese functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Contract code after correct `returns` to `return` there are lots of errors.

Just refer this code for changes where you face error in your code and you can freely ask questions regarding any changes in a comment if you don't get it.

```
pragma solidity>0.4.99<0.6.0;

contract Election {

struct Candidate {
    string name;
    uint voteCount; }

struct Voter {
    bool authorized;
    bool voted;
    uint vote; }

address public owner; string public electionName;

mapping(address => Voter) public voters; Candidate[] public candidates; uint public totalVotes;

modifier ownerOnly(){
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    _; }

constructor (string memory _name) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    electionName = _name; }

function addCanditate(string memory _name) ownerOnly public {
    candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0)); }

function getNameCandidate() public view returns(uint){
    return candidates.length; }

function authorize (address _person) ownerOnly public {
    voters[_person].authorized = true; }

function vote (uint _voteIndex) public {
    require(!voters[msg.sender].voted);
    require(voters[msg.sender].authorized);

    voters[msg.sender].vote = _voteIndex;
    voters[msg.sender].voted = true;

    candidates[_voteIndex].voteCount += 1;
    totalVotes += 1; } function end() ownerOnly public {
    selfdestruct(msg.sender); }

}
```

Comment: thanks, bro everything is okay now but when I want to deploy this contract I got one error:

creation of Election errored: Error encoding arguments: SyntaxError: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 1

Comment: No brother, I copied my code and paste on remix and it is deployed successfully without any error. If possible then copy my code and paste as it is and select compiler version `version:0.5.0+commit.1d4f565a.Emscripten.clang`.

Comment: I want to give a name for this election like "best student in the class"

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI96x.png

I want to give a name to this election like "Best student in the class"

so I got this error:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM2Su.png

Comment: You entering string value and remember remix always take string with in `" "`. so you have to enter `Best student in the class` as **"Best student in the class"**.
for more check image  [https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K67E.png]

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I want to ask you one more question. If I wanna see the candidates name so what code I need to write? like there is three candidates "Tom" "jerry" and Bell so how can I see the name in my contract?

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your code. First, as per the @shawn's comment, for returning any value, we use `return` not `returns` like other languages. Also a `struct` doesn't have a member `length`. So if you are looking to the get the length of `candidates` array. You should write it as:

```
function getNameCandidate() public view returns(uint){
    return candidates.length;
}
```

Comment: I changed returns to return and now I got two errors:
          function Election(string _name) public {
                    owner = msg.sender;
                    electionName = _name;
          }

          function addCanditate(string _name) ownerOnly public {
                     candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0));
          }
in tese functions

Comment: Please update the question with new errors

Answer (score 0):

So with the new versions of solidity the constructor is not defined as a function with the same name as the contract anymore. Define the following function as follows:

This function:

**function Election(string _name) public { owner = msg.sender; electionName = _name; }**
should be declared as:
**constructor(string _name) public { owner = msg.sender; electionName = _name; }**

Also in the newer versions of solidity you need to define where some variables will be stored. Thus just add memory to the next function as indicated below:

function addCanditate(string **memory** _name) ownerOnly public { candidates.push(Candidate(_name, 0)); }